# How does one compute a baseline for a stacked, moving line graph in D3.js?

Tags: layout, stack, d3.js

I'm trying to render a moving stream graph. I have simple line graphs moving, but stacks are throwing me off. Specifically, the baseline is being set to y0=height, where height is the height of the plot. The code below is my attempt to incorporate y0 but I'm getting parsing errors. The data in the following format:

```
data = [
           {
               "name": "foo"
               "values": [ {time: 1, value: 23}, {time: 2, value: 32}, ... ]
           },
           {
               "name": "bar"
               "values": [ {time: 1, value: 33}, {time: 2, value: 62}, ... ]
           },
           {
               "name": "baz"
               "values": [ {time: 1, value: 13}, {time: 2, value: 2}, ... ]
           },
           ...
       ];
```

The area generator looks like:

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
    .y0(function(d) { return height - y(d.y0); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value + d.y0); });
```

The stack layout looks like:

```
var stack = d3.layout.stack()
    .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
    .x(function(d) { return d.time; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .out(function(d, y0, y) {
        d.y0 = y0;
        d.value = d.value;
    });
```

Then, to generate my paths:

```
var path = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(stack(data))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });
```

I originally populate the data with value 0, so I'm not expecting to see anything at first. And it seems to work, with paths rendered.

The issue comes on the update. The path has parsing errors and hits NaN's at various spurts through the path generation, I assume because one of the accessors, y0, y, or x is undefined?

d="M328.60871678767865,104...{normal}...L395.02613982034944,NaNL395.02613982034944,NaNL401.6597510373444,NaNL401.6597510373444,NaNL401.6597510373444,NaNL401.6597510373444,NaNL401.6597510373444,NaNL401.6597510373444,NaNL401.6597510373444,NaNL401.6597510373444,NaNL395.02613982034944,NaNL395.02613982034944,NaNL395.02613982034944,NaNL395.02613982034944,NaNL388.3857526981277,NaNL388.3857526981277,NaNL388.3857526981277,NaNL388.3857526981277,NaNL381.7521414811327,NaNL381.7521414811327,NaNL381.7521414811327,NaNL381.7521414811327,NaNL375.111754358911,NaNL375.111754358911,NaN...{normal}...L330,0Z"

Here's the redraw function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    d3.select("#line" + id + "-" + i)
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
        .attr("transform", null);
}

xAxis.call(x.axis);
yAxis.call(y.axis);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    path.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ")");
} // the translation calculations can be safely ignored
```

Curious if anyone can pour some insight on this. Thanks!

Comment: what are your axis intervals? typically you have such "out of bounds errors" when you have values that are outside axis intervals... I would recommend to look at Bob Monteverde's NVD3 library to see a good stacked area chart that also has axis

Comment: My intervals seem to be accurate. The x axis ranges from now to ten minutes ago, and the y axis ranges from 0 to the max value in the series. I'll look at the library, but I'd rather stick to pure d3.